# Issue with using externals

Tags: webpack

Im trying to set an external using the obj/commonjs syntax but looking at the bundle its returning `module.exports = undefined`

heres my config:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    target: 'node',
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/utilities/')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    externals: {
        tessel: {
            commonjs: "tessel",
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `output.libraryTarget` to `commonjs`. Webpack uses the `libraryTarget` to determine the type of the import that is used for the externals. Change your `output` to:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
},
```

Source [webpack/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/f4c04d8f98c023f1ff7e06642133ea5ee6f107f3/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js#L192-L195)